# Desire2Learn Office Extensions not working correctly with Office 2010 and D2L 10

Tags: desire2learn

When we attempt to use Desire2Learn Office Extension with Office 2010 on Windows 7 against our development instance of D2L v10 the login integration does not work properly. I enter the URL for our development instance:

[Screenshot #1](http://s.lundrigan.ca/d87e6c.png)

When I click the "Login" button on the Desire2Learn tab in Word, I get a popup dialog with the standard D2L sign-in page:

[Screenshot #2](http://s.lundrigan.ca/7c6940.png)

But when I enter valid credentials I am redirected to the D2L org-level homepage within the same small popup window, which is not the expected behavior for the IDKey authentication redirect.  I haven't had much experience yet with D2L Valence APIs, but it appears that the initial request to /d2l/auth/api/token fails and am then redirected to the standard D2L login page.

Is there anyone here who has been able to successfully configure D2L 10 to work with the Office Extension who could assist me in getting this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some sites where the custom portal page for your organization's login does not pass the "target=" parameter through to the login step appropriately. Missing this results in "deeplinking" not working (which is in turn required during valence auth).

If you control your own portal page you may be able to update it directly.

Otherwise I would suggest that you open a support ticket with the Desire2Learn helpdesk, it is typically a quick change.